# How do I rewrite this line of code in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, url-rewriting

In the *C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4* book, in `gotocelldialog.cpp`, it has the following line of code:

```
okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
```

Can this line be *rewritten* as follows?

```
if (lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput())
okButton->setEnabled();
```

Comment: you're posting a lot of very basic questions that can be answered by reading the docs, and trying things out by yourself. please take a bit more time searching for the answers by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `setEnabled` requires a boolean parameter. See the documentation  for [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).

Answer (score 0):

Can be replaced by:

```
if (lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput()) 
okButton->setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: that's not equivalent. You need "else okButton->setEnabled(false);"